# What does the -u parameter mean in git push -u origin master?

Tags: git, push

I've been using `Bitbucket` from `Atlassian` and when I need to push some data into my repository I have to type the following command:

> git push -u origin master

In git documentation it's:

> git push origin master

Why do we need that special `-u` parameter? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [git manual for push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) (which can be viewed in the terminal with `man git-push`):

> **-u** 
> **--set-upstream**
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less [git-pull[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and other commands. For more information, see `branch.<name>.merge` in [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Simply put, it sets the push target as current branch's upstream.

Once you've issued `git push -u origin master` on branch `master`, you can simply `git push` without extra arguments on that branch and it will be equivalent to `git push origin master`.

Note that branch names don't have to match. You can set your local `master` to push to `origin/foo`, although it will be confusing. You can also still push to branches other than upstream explicitly, it won't overwrite the upstream setting.

The upstream branch can be set without pushing using [`git branch -u origin/master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--ultupstreamgt). Note that `origin/master` is an argument for the `-u` option, not for the `git branch` command in general, hence it must be specified in the `remoteName/branchName` format rather than two separate arguments: `remoteName branchName`.

Comment: If my `master`'s the name of the default branch than what's `origin`? _Simply put, it sets the push target as current branch's upstream._ **- By upstream you mean the data that's being uploaded to that branch, right?**

Comment: @JConstantine _upstream_ is the corresponding branch on a remote. _Remote_ is another repository that you can exchange commits (and branches, tags...) with. When cloning a repo git automatically adds it as a remote called `origin`. If that repo is a fork of another one it's customary to add the original one as a remote called `upstream` (which is confusing). See `man git-remote` for details.

Comment: _Remote is another repository that you can exchange commits (and branches, tags...) with._ **- You mean the one that's located on my HDD?** _If that repo is a fork of another one it's customary to add the original one as a remote called upstream_ **- As I'm a new user of git I didn't quite get it :(**

Comment: @JConstantine Typically the `origin` remote is on another server, like GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab or your private server (but git does support local remotes too). A _fork_ is when someone decides to make their own version of some software using it as a base, ie. the original project goes one way and your version goes the other (like a fork in a road). Have you read any git tutorials or maybe the official [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)?

Comment: I've only watched a couple of YouTube tutorials so far. Thank you for helping me out and giving a link to the book which I definitely should peruse.